# Loadrunner Flex protocol - issue with amf call

Tags: apache-flex, load-testing, loadrunner

I am trying to make load test for Flex application, but some error appear during replay. I can't understand why it's happening. I have done all correlations for DSID,

I'm using latest version of Externalizable Objects:
-  flex-messaging-common
-  flex-messaging-core
-  flex-messaging-data
-  flex-messaging-data-req
-  flex-messaging-opt
-  flex-messaging-proxy
-  flex-messaging-remoting

I have rerecorded script and I tried to find differences, but I didn't found anything significant. It's very confusing because first 20 amf_calls works fine.

Error Output:

```
Error:Decoding of AMF message failed. Error is : ReadValue Failed due Insufficient data  to read at location 6
```

I'm using Loadrunner 12, Flex protocol, IE 9.

### Edit. The line before error:

```
Warning:HTTP status code 500 was returned by the server
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 500 is typically associated with two states

(1) Missed correlation
(2) Application "coming off the tracks" where an unexpected response is sent back, but no check is made for an acceptable response.    One to two requests downstream you will have a 500 thrown for a request which is out of context with the state of the data or the application.

Record the application twice.   Compare the scripts.   Make sure you have handled all of the dynamic data.

Record a third time, change the data record used.  Make sure you have covered all of the business process specific dynamic elements

Record a fourth time with a different sign on credentials set.  Compare to previous recordings and make sure you have covered all of the dynamic elements related to user credentials.

Odds are you have missed a dynamic element related to the business process which is outside of Flex session and state items

Comment: I performed all four scripts, I didn't found new correlations, only new information about 'response' for problematic amf_call, that should be very huge.